# How to select rows which column value is greater but closest in desc order manner

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Let's say we have some values.

- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
- 8
- 9

Let's say I want to query value greater than 6 and limit is 2 but in desc order manner.
I want output 8,7

```sql
SELECT number FROM table WHERE number > 6 ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 2;
```

But it output 9,8. It match the query literally. But I want it output the closest value.

The sql I use is mysql-8.0 and sqlite.

Much appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to order the other way first, then order desc in an outer select

```
SELECT number 
FROM (
    SELECT number 
    FROM table 
    WHERE number > 6 
    ORDER BY number LIMIT 2
) AS t
ORDER BY number desc
```

Comment: it seems legit. works fine to me.

Comment: Amazingly, this works, too:  `(
    SELECT number 
    FROM table 
    WHERE number > 6 
    ORDER BY number LIMIT 2
) ORDER BY number DESC

Comment: @RickJames, it kind of makes sense, but I tried many of the DBMS at db<>fiddle and it worked for none of them. What version did you try against?

Comment: @Lennart - 8.0.30, via the commandline `mysql`.  But I _think_ I remember seeing it years ago in some older version.  It clearly works with `UNION`.

Comment: Had to be something temporarely, seems to work when I try it now